# Android Next and Done Buttons

Tags: android, textview

I am attempting to have the next and done buttons for two textviews to function normally. Text field 1 should move to text field two on next and text field 2 should close the keyboard/edit view on done. My XML is below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapp.LaunchCam"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="onCameraClick"
        android:text="@string/start" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_inline_large" android:contentDescription="@string/logo"/>

        <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:lines = "1"
        android:maxLines = "1"
        android:singleLine = "true"
        android:hint = "@string/enter_first_team_name"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/autoCompleteTextView2"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:lines = "1"
        android:maxLines = "1"
        android:singleLine = "true"
        android:hint = "@string/enter_second_team_name_optional_" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When using either of these buttons I get the runtime error

```
11-05 16:28:11.506: E/View(27606): hasTransientState decremented below 0: unmatched pair of setHasTransientState calls
```

Comment: use `android:imeOptions` and `android:imeActionId` to do this. read about the [available options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions)

Comment: @AbdallahAlaraby Make that an answer, and I'll accept. Worked great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done easily if I understood what you want, but I'm not sure : if you want to quicky move to the next textfield, Android provides **imeOptions** : the Enter key of the keyboard will change to an arrow to move to the next text field with `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`, or to a "Go" button when it's the last one with android:imeOptions="actionGo" or `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`. So you don't need to put a next button in your app.
See this page of the documentation for mor information
https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Answer (score 1):

use android:imeOptions and android:imeActionId to do this. read about the [available options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions)